# Upgraded to 16.04 now GUI doesn't start

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, software-center

**Background**

I was running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the software center had been nagging to update to 16.04. Today clicked on the [Update] button in the Software Center.

**Current state**

Reboot proceeds until

> ```
>      Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen
> ```

then multiple blank lines and

> [  OK  ] Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.

I can <Super> F1 to login on tty1. I see

> New release '16.04.1 LTS' available.
>   Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

<strike>Since the upgrade does not appear to have been successful I'm reluctant to try it without advice.</strike>
I tried `do-release-upgrade`. It said `No new release found`.

Running `lsb_release -a` gives

> No LSB modules are available.
>   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>   Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
>   Release:        16.04
>   Codename:       xenial

I tried `startx` and it appeared to start. I stopped it by `sudo stop lightdm`.

If I try `sudo service lightdm start` the screen alternately displays a mouse pointer and then the text boot screen, for about 5 seconds.

**Edit**

I tried `sudo apt-get update` and got errors such as

> Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/xenial-security InRelease
>    Temporary failure resolving security.ubuntu.com

Looks like I don't have network support - `ping localhost` gets `ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted`

**Question**

Assuming that the upgrade has not completed, what should I do next to get to a system that boots to the GUI?

Alternatively, is it possible to back out of the update? I still have my 14.4 DVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution was to revert to the previous version.

I booted from my original "Ubuntu 14.04.3 desktop amd64" DVD, and

- At the welcome screen, clicked the "Try Ubuntu" button and made sure my most recent backup was current.
- Rebooted again, then at the welcome screen clicked "Install Ubuntu".
- At the "Preparing to install Ubuntu" screen clicked continue.
- At the "Installation type" screen, there are four options. I clicked the bottom one "Something else".
- A partition map is then shown, including check boxes that determine which partition is to be over-written. Firstly, I have to admit my notes here are sketchy. I have to say I found this screen quite confusing. Since I wanted to retain my data, I was very careful to avoid the checkboxes in the "Format?" column. The feedback on this screen is poor; it kept telling me to do things to the partition map. Since there is nothing labelled "Partition map" it took me a while to work that this screen is it.
- Eventually I selected my ext4 partition. /dev/sda as the device for the boot loader, and clicked "Install Now".
- According to [How to re-install Ubuntu keeping your data and settings](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2057342) there are three prompts that it's important to get right if you want to have easy access to your old data. These are
- Your full name.
- Your user name.
- Your machine name.

Few notes

- I didn't test what happens if the full name or machine name are different, but obviously the user name needs to be right. I would expect that an incorrect username would be fixable, with work.
- When you have to select the filesystem, select "Ext4 journaling filesystem". All the documentation seems to just call it Ext4 without mentioning the journaling part.

**And then**

Having got a working 14.04 system, I had no Wifi or DVD support. I Googled and messed about for days. All sorts of posts in various places suggest building your own, with all that would entail in the future. Eventually, I tried the "Advanced boot options" in the Grub menu.

I selected the previous kernel, and *viola* everything works!

Hope that helps someone else.